# Services and Repositories in DDD (C#)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

How do `Services` and `Repositories` relate to each other in DDD? I mean, I've been reading up on DDD for the past 2 days and everywhere I go, there's always a `Service` layer and there's always a `Repository` layer. How do these differentiate or compliment each other?

From what I've read, isn't the `Repository` the layer responsible for delegating interactions between the application and the data?

So, what's the need for the `Service` layer if it has to implement the `Repository` to interact with the data anyway even though the `Repository` probably already implements the methods needed to do so?

I'd appreciate some enlightenment on the subject.

P.S. Don't know if this will help any, but I'm working with an ASP.NET MVC 2 application in which I'm trying to implement the Repository pattern. I just finished implementing the Dependency Injection pattern (for the first time ever)...

**UPDATE**

Okay, with so many answers, I think I understand what the difference is. So, to review (correct me if I'm wrong):

- A `Repository` layer interacts only with a single object out of the database or the ORM, `IEmployeeRepository` -> `Employee`.
- A `Service` layer encapsulates more complex functionality on objects returned from `Repositories`, either one or multiple.

So, then I have a sub question. Is it considered bad practice to create abstract objects to be sent to my views? For example an `AEmployee` (`A` for `abstract` because to me `I` means `interface`) which contains properties from `Employee` and `X` or `X`?

Actually, one more subquestion. If a `Service` layer can be considered "tuned" for an application does it need to be implemented with an interface?

Comment: I believe services can aggregate multiple repositories.

Comment: There's quite a discrepancy between the common/popular usage of Repository's and Service's (the usage found in many examples & tutorials) and how Domain Driven Design defines these.  I believe it is important to understand the differences.

Comment: @Sergey is right - there should be one repository per aggregate root, but a service can (and will) work across multiple reposities, made possible by the unit of work pattern. and by the way - how many times can a question like this be asked? there are plenty of questions regarding this on stack overflow.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

True, a repository works with data (ie. SQL, Webservice etc.) but that's the *only* job. CRUD operations, nothing more. There is no place for stored procedure based busines logic.

The service (or business logic layer) provides the functionality. *How* to fullfill a business request (ie. calculate salary), *what* you have to do.

Oh, and this is a really nice DDD book:
http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly

Comment: With you entirely except for you can't call stored procs.  Why not - if you can return data from a view, why not return data from a stored procedure?

Comment: This assumes no stored procedures?  If you do have stored procedures where is the calling code if not in the repository? I wouldn't agree that the repository pattern precludes business logic in stored procedures.  The repository encapsulates all database interactions - both CRUD and stored procedures.

Comment: @ Michael Shimmins: I think it's not a good practice to split busines logic into pieces. If I have a business layer, I should all of my domain logic host there. Of course I have 'smart' stored procedures too ie. for fast reporting. But sp has _nothing_ to do with business logic. Leastways in DDD.

Comment: @James Gaunt: no. Of course stored procedures are great. I said that avoid *business logic* in stored procedures.

Comment: "The service (or business logic layer) implements the domain logic" - I'm sorry, but that is not DDD at all.  It's an anti-pattern in DDD.

Comment: Why no business logic in stored procedures?  I think this is an unnecessary constraint.  Some business logic is much more naturally implemented in the database.  There are some good reasons for not using stored procedures for complex logic - but most of them stem from not having much skill in SQL in the team.  Business logic should exist in the domain service - but the repository is part of the domain service.

Comment: @qstarin - I think you're talking about the anemic domain model, correct?  The term "service" is so overused that I don't think anyone can state that it's a pattern or anti-pattern without seeing exactly how it's used.

Comment: @Mayo: Correct.  The term "Service" is not overused inside of Domain Driven Design.  That is why I say there is an important distinction between these terms inside of DDD and outside of DDD.

Comment: @qstarin: true, I'm not precise, I'll correct it. But at first time "service is connection point for many objects" and others are maybe too dusty. That's why I've linked Eric Evan's book (see url).

Comment: @James Gaunt: there are exceptions, but in the common case - imho - it's hard to ensure cohesion. Domain objects and SQL sp...it seems a hard way for me:) Have you maybe articles/blogposts about this?

Comment: @boj - no articles sorry - this is just opinion.  I work mainly in web applications where at the end of the day the database is the application - once the page request ends it's all that's left.  In these cases it's often much better to execute logic on the DB rather than haul lots of state out of the database to make comparisons or decisions only to throw it all away again milliseconds later.  It's part of the idiom of taking the processing to the data - rather than taking the data to the processing.

Comment: @boj: "service is connection point" - That's a great way to explain a Domain Service.  It is an entry point for clients.  It takes Commands (often as a DTO, or basically a bag of simple properties) and carries them out by invoking the correct methods on Entities.

Comment: @James:  Better how?  You seem to imply better performance ("haul lots of state"), but that seems like a concern that would often be irrelevant (I can pull 100k Entities out of the DB in the same amount of time it takes the browser to download jquery.js).  Sprocs, ime, tend to complicate, or make practically impossible, parts of DDD (Events would be a first mention).  Plus, also ime, mixing logic between app and db has an exponentially bad effect on maintenance effort as application size & complexity grows.

Comment: How about general "external" operations like "EmailSender" class? If not in the application business logic but you can't call it a Provider because grammatically it would be incorrect. Would the name EmailSendingService make sense?

Answer (score 30):

The Service will use a Repository to retrieve an Entity and then call methods on it (the Entity) to perform the Command/task.

Answer (score 12):

As a concrete example a Shopping Cart application might have the following services:

**ShoppingCartService** - manages a cart of items with add/remove/update support etc.

**OrderService** - take a cart, converts it to an order and handles the payment process etc.

each of these services needs to talk a "data source" for CRUD operations. This is where the Repository pattern comes in handy as it abstracts the loading and saving of data to and from the data source be it a database, web service or even in-memory cache.

When you want to create a quick prototype of your application without having to deal with database setup, schema, stored procedures, permissions, etc. you can create a cache or fake repository in a matter of minutes.

For the example above your prototype might start off with the following:

- FakeCustomerRepository
- FakeAddressRepository
- FakeCartRepository
- FakeCartLineItemRepository
- FakeOrderRepository
- FakeOrderLineItemRepository

once your prototype is ready to evolve to the next level you can implement these against a real database:

- SQLCustomerRepository
- SQLAddressRepository
- SQLCartRepository
- SQLCartLineItemRepository
- SQLOrderRepository
- SQLOrderLineItemRepository

Comment: From some examples I have seen there would be a Project.Repository class library and as a Project.Service class library to house the classes you listed above. I typically see a Project.Model class library as well. Where do you place the interfaces for the repository classes, in Project.Model?

Comment: I usually have a respository and models folder inside my Project.Service project. Then I have /Repository/Interfaces, /Repository/FakeRepository, /Repository/SQLRepository, /Models, /Service/Interfaces, /Service/[implementation classes]. I don't usually share repositories across services because my repositories are tailored specifically to the models within that service.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can remember, the repository is the final class before the data.  The service class can act on data retrieved from the repository.  The repository is really just meant to get data to somebody else to do the work.  The service layer can provide things such as business logic that all data must pass through.  It could also provide for a translation between the application logic and the data layer.  But again, this is just what I can remember.

Answer (score 4):

There's no golden standard that defines a service or a repository.  In my applications a repository is (as you say) an interface into a database.  A service has full access to a repository - but the service exposes a subset of functionality to its consumers.

Think of the repository as more low level.  The repository has to expose many ways of accessing the underlying database.  A service might combine calls to a repository with other code that only makes sense at a code level (i.e. not in the database),  such as access to other state in the application, or validation/business logic that can't easily be applied in a database.